Why is `array % 1` running 150% slower for smaller numbers than larger ones?
I would understand if numpy was smart enough to see that array % 1 gives a constant result (for that dtype), and that its runtime was independent of the input. I would also understand if runtime was longer for larger numbers, maybe because dividing a large number takes longer (compare Why is floating-point division in Python faster with smaller numbers?). But why does array % 1 run longer for smaller numbers?
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.randint(500,        size=20_000_000, dtype=np.int32) - 250
a2 = np.random.randint(20_000_000, size=20_000_000, dtype=np.int32) - 250

print(timeit(lambda: a1 % 1, number=5))
print(timeit(lambda: a2 % 1, number=5))
print(timeit(lambda: a1 % 1, number=5))
print(timeit(lambda: a2 % 1, number=5))

Output:
0.4755298000000039
0.19294559999980265
0.460197700000208
0.19560679999995045

Numpy information:
{'numpy_version': '2.0.0',
  'python': '3.12.4 (tags/v3.12.4:8e8a4ba, Jun  6 2024, 19:30:16) [MSC v.1940 '
            '64 bit (AMD64)]',
  'uname': uname_result(system='Windows', node='hostname', release='11', version='10.0.22631', machine='AMD64')},
 {'simd_extensions': {'baseline': ['SSE', 'SSE2', 'SSE3'],
                      'found': ['SSSE3',
                                'SSE41',
                                'POPCNT',
                                'SSE42',
                                'AVX',
                                'F16C',
                                'FMA3',
                                'AVX2',
                                'AVX512F',
                                'AVX512CD',
                                'AVX512_SKX',
                                'AVX512_CLX',
                                'AVX512_CNL',
                                'AVX512_ICL'],
                      'not_found': []}}]


I cannot reproduce this with numpy 1.26.4. All 4 run in ~0.42-0.45 sec.

I reproduce it with numpy 1.26.2 and numpy 2.0.0

I can reproduce this with numpy 2.0.0 on Linux but not on macOS (Intel). (Haven't tried numpy 1.26 on Linux.)

I think it is probably caused by the branch prediction. For example, a3 = np.sort(a1) is fast, while a4 = a2 * np.sign(a1) is slow.

If I change it to - 10_000_000 so that ~half the numbers are negative and half positive like the first array, I get the same time in both cases. And if I change it so that all numbers are negative, it's again fast.

Agree with @ken. perf record -e branch-misses shows that in the fast case there are ~18 million branch misses vs ~68 million in the slow one. Not sure why this doesn't happen on macOS.

I did similar using a1 and plot the time over the range of offset values. You can see it increase as the value gets close to 250 then decrese again.

@Dogbert is that the slow time for all of the values on mac os?

@matt yeah, the macOS time is closer to the slow Linux time.

I made a mistake in measurements - the branch misses difference is even bigger - 1 billion vs 20 million.

"if numpy was smart enough to see that array % 1 does not do anything" it does do something. It does the same thing to every value, it sets them to zero.

@matt good point, fixed the question.

@Dogbert Clang should explain why you cannot reproduce this on MacOS (see my answer for more information), but on Linux with Numpy 2.0. However, it is weird you cannot reproduce it with 1.26.4. Was your first test performed on MacOS? The code did not seem to change since and I can reproduce that with the two versions on my Linux (also on 2 Windows machines).

@JérômeRichard Yes, my first test was on macOS. I can only reproduce this on Linux. (I don't have Windows to test.)

TL;DR: the effect is caused by a combination of multiple technical details. It not only due to a branch prediction issue (as stated in the comment), but also due to the Numpy implementation which is not optimized for this use-case combined with poor compiler optimizations (especially GCC/MSVC). Compiling Numpy with Clang fixes the issue.

Under the hood
To perform this operation, Numpy calls the function generic_wrapped_legacy_loop with another function called INT_remainder passed in argument. The later computes the modulus for a single array item. It is generated from a relatively convoluted generic code (hard to locate) which can be found here. In your case, the function can be basically simplified to the following code:
static void INT_remainder(char **args, npy_intp const *dimensions, npy_intp const *steps, void *NPY_UNUSED(func)
{
    BINARY_LOOP {
        const int in1 = *(int*)ip1; // An item of the input array
        const int in2 = *(int*)ip2; // The divisor which is set to 1

        // Overflow check
        if (NPY_UNLIKELY((in2 == 0) || (in1 == NPY_MIN_INT && in2 == -1))) {
            FLAG_IF_DIVIDEBYZERO(in2);
            *(int *)op1 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle mixed case the way Python does
            const int rem = in1 % in2;
            if ((in1 > 0) == (in2 > 0) || rem == 0) {
                *(int*)op1 = rem;
            }
            else {
                *(int*)op1 = rem + in2;
            }
        }
    }
}

The first condition is an overflow check which should never happen in your case and it should be cheap since it is defined as being unlikely. In the second part, rem should be always 0 in your case since in2 is 1. Thus, the if condition is always true. However, it is executed lazily (from the left to the right) as defined in the C/C++ standard. This means in1 > 0 and in2 > 0 are evaluated first and then the equality, and finally rem == 0 only if the first is not true. The thing is in1 > 0 is sometimes true and sometimes false. The outcome of the in1 > 0 condition is dependent of the input array which is unpredictable. This is a problem for performance due to branch prediction. For more information, please read What is Branch Prediction?.
The second use-case (a2) is faster because the condition is more often true so your CPU can predict that the value will be likely be true and speculatively take the resulting associated conditional branch. Meanwhile, in the first case, the CPU cannot predict the outcome of the condition so you pay the overhead of unpredictable conditional branch (e.g. pipeline stall).
This effect can be confirmed by profiling the assembly code of Numpy on my machine.

Notes and discussion
The fact that branch prediction is an issue here is sad here, because the outcome of the condition is eventually always true! If the condition was rem == 0 || (in1 > 0) == (in2 > 0), then there would not be any performance issue in this case. However, the issue would be with positive random integers  modulo 2 (which is more frequent)...
**While (in1 > 0) == (in2 > 0) is supposed to be a branch-less implementation, the target compiler choose to generate conditional branches in this case resulting in the observed effect. It would not be an issue with a branch-less assembly code. A branch-less implementation is often a bit slower than a well-predicted conditional branch and (significantly) faster than a miss-predicted conditional branch. Thus, it seems a good idea here.

Experimental solution
The target compiler is GCC (10.2) on my machine running on Linux. GCC tends to unfortunately generate such a code. pip packages (like the one of Numpy) are generally built with GCC on Linux and AFAIK MSVC on Windows (generating a code often worst than GCC -- especially here). However, one can compile Numpy with another compiler. It turns out that Clang seems to generate a better code in this case (see on GodBolt). You can now easily build Numpy 2.0 with Clang and test that using the following commands:
# Packages Debian testing: sudo apt install virtualenv libpython3.13-dev build-essential pkg-config clang
cd /tmp
virtualenv venv
./venv/bin/pip install ipython meson ninja cython spin
export PATH=$PWD/venv/bin:$PATH
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
cd numpy
git checkout v2.0.0
git submodule update --init
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
spin ipython

Here are the results on my machine (i5-9600KF CPU):
GCC 13.2.0 (i.e. with conditional branches):
    0.7204837069984933
    0.2300826290011173
    0.7204179290001775
    0.23008121000020765

Clang 16.0.6 (i.e. without conditional branches):
    0.31062674399800017
    0.3103496809999342
    0.31044369300070684
    0.3100759939989075

As expected, Clang produces a branch-less assembly code which is faster than the version using conditional branch of GCC when they are miss-predicted but not otherwise. It does not have the observed performance issue.
Note that Clang is the default compiler on MacOS so users running on MacOS should not observe this problem.
Please note that both implementation are sub-optimal for integers since they do not benefit from SIMD instruction (though this is not easy because there is no div/idiv instructions on mainstream CPUs). Not to mention one can just set the final array to 0 in this very-specific (unlikely) use-case.

Wow. Nothing more to say.

So to this kind of scenario there are many answers but from my knowledge it should be either,

CPU Caches or branch prediction
How the data is being distributed
The vectorization area
Or the main issue can the potential type conversion

The best thing which you can do is use external tool to profile this and check. there is tool which can be used with python and this is called cProfile i rarely use this but in order to implement this its very easy.
You can use the code below to profile this.
def profile_code():
a1 % 1
a2 % 1

cProfile.run('profile_code()', 'output.pstats')
p = pstats.Stats('output.pstats')
p.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(10)


This might be a good answer if you can show the results demonstrate the problem. In the comments @Dogbert demonstrated that the number of branch predictions is different. Does your technique show similar results?
